# How to authenticate URL from Spotipy on Linux with no browser

Tags: google-cloud-platform, spotipy

I'm trying to run a python script that uses spotipy, which needs a url link to be opened to authenticate the login. unfortunately I'm running this on the google cloud shell, so I can't open the browser link. and for some reason when I open it in my browser, it just redirects to localhost and doesn't authenticate (localhost is the Redirect URI). how can I authenticate?

I've tried opening the link on my MacBook instead of the linux virtual machine but just got redirected to localhost and nothing happens. I've tried xdg-open, curl, but haven't gotten anywhere.

Edit: I tried this -

import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util
from config import CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, PLAY_LIST, USER
import random

token = util.oauth2.SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=CLIENT_ID, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET)

cache_token = token.get_access_token()
spotify = spotipy.Spotify(cache_token)

results1 = spotify.user_playlist_tracks(USER, PLAY_LIST, limit=100, offset=0)

But got the error that only valid bearer authentication is accepted, so apparently it's kind of working. I'm not sure how to make the bearer valid.

Edit 2:
Solved it with these posts:
[How to auth in spotipy without open web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67268587/how-to-auth-in-spotipy-without-open-web-browser)
[Persistent issues with Spotify Web API redirect URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64724102/persistent-issues-with-spotify-web-api-redirect-uri)

Comment: Delete this question as it has already been asked (do not post duplicate questions). Then upvote the question and answer if they helped you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.